# The match function not working in Java

Tags: java, string

I am doing some match functions with the Java. I have some string like this
park,reserved_parking etc..
If i search for the word park like this

```
if(input.trim().contains ("Park"))
dummies = dummies + "   1";
else 
dummies = dummies + "   0";
```

It prints the values for reserved_parking also. I don't know how to find the exact match in Java. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for `input.trim().equals("Park")`?

Comment: @marstran, this wont work to search in whole string!!

Comment: ya my problem is if i check for park it prints reserved_parking  also

Comment: @arunabimaniyu, title is wrong. `contains` is doing its work, but your need is different.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava I didn't understand his question. That is why I asked.

Comment: i no ...the problem is equal method also not working.If i use contains method then it takes all the values

Comment: @arunabimaniyu problem is with `case search`, matched string is `Park` whereas input contains `park` or `reserved_parking `, note `p` is small here, answer posted

Comment: @arunabimaniyu How does your chosen answer answer your question? I somehow don't see how this solved your problem at all. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to go for **case in-sensitive search**,

> change both the input and matched String to Upper case/lower case and
>   then match

.

**Input - park**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "park";
        if (input.trim().toUpperCase().contains("Park".toUpperCase()))
            dummies = dummies + "   1";
        else
            dummies = dummies + "   0";

        System.out.println(dummies);
    }
```

**Output**

```
   1
```

**Input - reserved_parking**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "reserved_parking";
        if (input.trim().toUpperCase().contains("Park".toUpperCase()))
            dummies = dummies + "   1";
        else
            dummies = dummies + "   0";

        System.out.println(dummies);
    }
```

**Output**

```
   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Contains does what it says. It tests if the String you give as input, is somewhere in the String you test against. So `"batteryparkhorsewidow".contains("park")` will return `true`.

What you are looking for may be the equals method. This method tests for String equality. So it will only return `true` if your String is "park" nothing more, nothing less.

Please mind that `equals` works case sensitive. For a case insensitive equality check use `equalsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 0):

It seems a case issue. You can lowercase or uppercase the string before checking it.

```
input.trim().toUpperCase().contains("PARK")
```

Or use some external library like Apache Commons Lang's [containsIgnoreCase](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

```
StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(input, "Park");
```

Answer (score 0):

To find an exact match, you will need a Regular Expression, like this:

```
private boolean isMatching(String source, String stringToSearch){
     String pattern = "\\b" + stringToSearch + "\\b";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
     Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
     return m.find();
}
```

The \b option in the regular expression means "word bonduary". So, this will match exactly "Park" if you pass that as a parameter in the stringToSearch, but it won't match "reserved_parking", returning false.

Comment: For finding exact matches a regular expression is a bit over the top, isn't it?